# Redirect Express js piped (req.pipe) res properly

Tags: express

Probably I'm doing something wrong but:

In my browser I have a code

```
window.location = '/some/url'
```

or element with href="/some url"

in node (express.js) I have following route handler:

```
app.get('/some/url', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('http://www.google.com')
});
```

Content of the page is loaded with strange flaw Google page. And address bar is not changed (http://localhost:3000/some/url).

I'm making request via intermediate server using
req.pipe(request(host + req.url)).pipe(res) and it seems that piped res does not redirect properly. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: You need to give us more details. It works for me, so there must be something strange you're doing.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm using server redirect: req.pipe(request(host + req.url)).pipe(res) and it seems that piped res does not redirect. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: There is no need to pipe a redirect response. Piping is for very long file transfers (like a video download). A redirect will fit in a single packet and should be sent simply as you have in your sample above. Just do that.

Comment: Hm, I'm using request.js to redirect dev server GET requests to server with the service (that should redirect res to www.google.com). And I don't know how to redirect GET without pipe: request.get(host + req.url).pipe(res); And I need to redirect GET to other server, because www.google.com is just sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use {folllowRedirect: false} option for reqest.js